# Is there an youtube API to "heart" a comment?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Heart sign to comments can be give by owner of the channel to any comment, is there a way to do via api like how we can reply to a comment etc.

Comment: Currently, there's no API that will insert a heart comment. You can probably use [`CommentThreads:insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert#usage) to create a top-level comment and to add a reply to an existing comment, use the [`comments.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) method instead.

Comment: The question is not about inserting comments but about marking existing comments with heart mark.